# Bookshelf ORM How to define Model attributes and datatypes

Tags: node.js, express, bookshelf.js

Am using Bookshelf.js ORM for my Express.js app, In the Bookshelf ORM only given example for Defining model and association..

I don't find anywhere, How to define model attributes and dataTypes like

```
name: {
  type: string
}
age: {
  type: number
}
```

Need help.. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. The attributes and their types are taken *from the database schema*. The closest you get to defining attributes in Bookshelf are the key definitions: primary and foreign keys. But even then you are restricted to their names and key semantics only, the types are decided upon their database types.

If however you want to define them in code you can use the Knex [Schema Builder](http://knexjs.org/#Schema) and [Migrations](http://knexjs.org/#Migrations) features. Like:

```
// 0001_people.js
'use strict';

exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('people', function(table) {
    table.increments('id').primary();
    table.string('name').unique().notNullable();
    table.integer('age').notNullable();
  });
};

exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.dropTable('people');
};
```

But keep in mind those definitions are not tied to the corresponding Bookshelf model. Is your duty to keep them in sync.

Comment: So if I want my columns to be defined on the Bookshelf Model (for general reference) and even if I'm ready to define them manually - I won't be able to??

Comment: Yes @jayarjo. What I have been doing is defining them using knex as mentioned in the answer. I have `migrations` directories containing prefixed-javascript-files for each table, something like "0001_people.js", "0002_people.js", etc. So, the prefix sets the sequence the scripts should be run.